# Java - Bolt Configuration for Neo4j 3.0.0-M01 Embedded

Tags: java, apache-spark, neo4j, connector

I am using the EMBEDDED version of neo4j 3.0.0-M01 and the neo4j-spark connector for my java project, and i am not able to properly configure bolt.

The instructions on the official github project for the connector (https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-spark-connector) refers only to the case of a running standalone server (on localhost for example), which is not my case.

Here is the snippet of code from my project that is involved in the configuration of bolt:

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("TestApp").setMaster("local[8]");
    conf.set("spark.neo4j.bolt.url","bolt://C/neo4j_test/neo4j-community-3/data/graph-repo.db");
```

If i comment the line containing the conf.set() method,then launch the standalone (not the embedded) neo4j server on localhost on port 7474 and then execute my code, the connection is successful. Otherwise i get this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: hostname can't be null
at java.net.InetSocketAddress.checkHost(Unknown Source)
at java.net.InetSocketAddress.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.connector.socket.SocketClient$ChannelFactory.create(SocketClient.java:243)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.connector.socket.SocketClient.start(SocketClient.java:75)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.connector.socket.SocketConnection.<init>(SocketConnection.java:63)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.connector.socket.SocketConnector.connect(SocketConnector.java:52)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.pool.InternalConnectionPool.acquire(InternalConnectionPool.java:113)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.InternalDriver.session(InternalDriver.java:53)
at org.neo4j.spark.Executor$.execute(Neo4j.scala:360)
at org.neo4j.spark.Neo4jRDD.compute(Neo4j.scala:408)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:86)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Even the Neo4j Manual does not explain how to refer to an embedded instance, as you can see in the following extract from chapter 4: (https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/drivers/):

4.3.1.1. Bolt URI format

A Bolt URI follows the standard URI pattern of scheme://host:port. For example, bolt://203.0.113.1:1234 would connect using the Bolt protocol to 203.0.113.1 on port 1234. A hostname can be used instead of an IP address: bolt://server:1234. The default Bolt port is 7687.

Comment: Why are you using a pre-3.0 milestone build that's unsupported, vs the latest 3.0 build?

Comment: @David Makogon because the 3.0 milestone uses lucene 3.6. In my project i use the same lucene version for other purposes, and since the latest relases of neo4j use the version 5, they all cause problems and conflicts